# Как растянуть картинку на всю доступную ширину

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Есть `ImageView`  которое находится внутри `LinearLayout`. Т.к.  у картинки может быть как вертикальная так и горизонтальная ориентация выглядят они соответственно тоже по разному, можно ли как то вставить картинку (растянуть ее) на всю доступную  ширину, при этом зафиксировав значение высоты. Т.е. что  бы  в прямоугольнике с фиксированной высотой и шириной равной размерам контейнера в котором находится `ImageView` можно было установить картинку (либо ее фрагмент), что бы при любой ориентации картинки они смотрелись одинаково?

вот что у меня получилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**image_view.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_message_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    />
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, возможно вам нужен  `android:scaleType="параметр"`? поиграйтесь с "параметром", чтобы найти нужное вам поведение. Например, fitXY втискивает картинку в заданные ширину и высоту.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_message_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

Параметр `scaleType` отвечает за размер самой картинки, установленной при помощи `src` (для `background` не будет работать!). Размер самого объекта ImageView не зависит от размера изначальной картинки.

`scaleType="centerCrop"` означает, что картинка будет увеличена (сохраняя пропорции) до тех пор, пока хотя бы одно измерение не будет равно размеру `ImageView`. Все, что будет вылезать, видно не будет (от англ. **crop** - обрезать).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло